# skip an array element before copying into another array perl

Tags: arrays, perl

Here is my array.

@resources = (a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)

Now i want to copy this entire array into another one but it should skip the element which is stored in $skip.

For example, if $skip=a3.

Then the new array should have only these elements:

resourcesleft=(a1,a2,a4,a5)

Can someone please let me know how can i get this?

Regards,

Chandu

Answer (score 1):

Use the [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) builtin function

```
@resourcesleft = grep { $_ ne $skip } @resources;
```